# Passing Functions to Functions

Tags: python, function, timer

currently I am getting errors in python but I cannot seem to find them

```
def dictionaryObjectParsed():
    a = []
    b = []
    a, b = zip(*(map(lambda x: x.rstrip('\n\r').split('\t'), open('/Users/settingj/Desktop/NOxMultiplier.csv').readlines())))
    for x in range(0,len(a)):
        print a[x]
        print b[x]

def timer(f):
    threading.Timer(1, timer, f).start()
    print time.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p %Z')

timer(dictionaryObjectParsed)
```

Heres the error I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 756, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: timer() argument after * must be a sequence, not function
```

I was able to do this earlier but I think I did something to create this error, what the heck :(

I clearly am passing arguments to the timer function ... right?

**EDIT**

I also tried `timer(dictionaryObjectParsed)` but nothing...

Also, sorry for the noobie question this is just my second day in python... :P

Comment: Show the full traceback and double-check that the code you posted here is identical with the code that produces said traceback.

Comment: `dictionaryObjectParsed()` actually returns `None`, so one argument is being passed to `timer`.

Comment: Ca you explain what you hope this line will do: `threading.Timer(1,timer).start()` ? Are you trying to do a time-delayed recursion of some kind?

Comment: Yes, I am attempting to call dictionaryObjectParsed() every second with the time printed after

Comment: Oh, that's not what that line does. I'll post an answer.

Comment: It doesn't look like `timer` is even doing anything with `f`.

Comment: I made an edit, i would like to print the function f every second

Comment: What do you think `print f` does? What it *doesn't* do is invoke the `dictionaryObjectParsed()` function.

Comment: I made an edit, do you see any issues now? Now i get a different error, ill post an edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the function without calling it (drop the '()')..

```
timer(dictionaryObjectParsed)
```

and

```
def timer(f):
    threading.Timer(1,f).start()
    print time.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p %Z')
```

instead of

```
threading.Timer(1,timer)
```

You are trying to create a recursive timer function, I think, by mistake. The error you are getting, is calling the function 'timer' again, without the function parameter. I think it was a simple mistake.

---

Ok, so you do want a recursive function, so try this:

```
def timer(f):
    threading.Timer(1,timer,[f,]).start()
    f()
    print time.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p %Z')
```

worked?

Comment: i tired that, no fix :(

Comment: found another detail, maybe now?
edit your question with the error you are getting anyway...

Comment: this fixes the crash issue but now timer isn't being called again after a second, the function is only being outputted once

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors.

Try this:

```
def timer(f):
    f()                           # NOTE THIS NEW LINE
    threading.Timer(1,timer, f).start()  # NOTE CHANGE ON THIS LINE
    print time.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p %Z')

timer(dictionaryObjectParsed)     # NOTE CHANGE ON THIS LINE
```

Note that on the final line, you want to pass the function, not the result of the invoking the function.

Note that on the line `threading.Timer ...`, you want to pass enough arguments that subsequent invokations of `timer()` have the correct number of args.

Note the new line -- without it, `dictionaryObjectParsed` will never be invoked!

Answer (score 0):

The actual syntax of instantiating a [Timer Instance](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Timer) is

```
threading.Timer(interval, function, args=[], kwargs={})
```

There are 2 problems in your implementation

1. You are registering a function that accepts 1 argument without passing any argument to your registered function
2. You are recursively registering the caller function in the timer routine.

I believe, your intention is to register the function argument rather than the caller function. That would eventually change your implementation to

```
def timer(f):
    threading.Timer(1,f).start()
    print time.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p %Z')
```

But due to some odd reasons, you want to register the caller function, you need to also pass the argument as a parameter to threading.Timer, conforming to the syntax in the documentation

```
def timer(f):
    threading.Timer(1,timer, f).start()
    print time.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p %Z')
```